# How can i remove specific characters from htaccess or redirect such URL

Tags: security, .htaccess

I have some url's

eg

abc.com/page.php?page=abc

and

abc.com/page.php?page=abc/yzy

now what i want is 
either remove ' / ' from the parameter and rewrite the url
or redirect it to abc.com

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use `mod_rewrite` if you are using Apache to do it very easily. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Here you have a tutorial to do it: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

It is a module to do this kind of things.
If you need more help just say it.